# Wordpress multisite - menu in footer of one domain is referencing the menus of a different site on the multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I'm working on a multisite and in my footer.php and in one of the domains I have this menu that is referencing a menu from a different site in the multisite. I know on the blog page the correct one is being used but elsewhere it isn't and I'm not sure why. Is there a way that I can ask it to stay referencing the current site's menu for the footer?

```
<div class='right-half-wrapper'>
    <?php 
        wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'menu'  => 5,
                'container_id'    => 'navbarNavDropdown',
                'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav ml-auto d-flex flex-row',
                'fallback_cb'     => '',
                'depth'           => 4,
                'walker'          => new Understrap_WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
            )
        );
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is showing the menu from a different site, then the most likely explanation is that you (or a plugin maybe) have switched to a different blog somewhere before this. That is usually done using `switch_to_blog`, so try if calling `restore_current_blog` before you try to output the menu, fixes it.

Comment: Yes, as @CBroe mentioned, [switch_to_blog](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/) and [restore_current_blog](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/restore_current_blog/) should provide a solution

Comment: restore_current_blog() before the output of the menu returned nothing for some reason even though the id was correct so I ended up just switch_to_blog( id of current page)